# Show that Matrix $M$ is diagonizable if the characteristic polynomial is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, irreducible-polynomials, diagonalization

Let $K$ be a field with $K \subset \mathbb C$, $ M \in M_{n}(K)$ so that $\chi_{M} \in K[X]$ is irreducible. Prove that $M \in M_{n}(\mathbb C)$ is diagonalizable.

My path so far: Since $\chi_{M}$ irreducible that means $M$ has a maximum of one eigenvector with maximum multiplicity of $1$. Let $\lambda$ be this eigenvalue. The eigenspace $V_{\lambda}$ therefore can only be one-dimensional?! So how can $\dim_{K}(V_{\lambda})=n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we're working over a subfield of $\mathbb C$, no irreducible polynomial has multiple roots in $\mathbb C$. And if all roots of the characteristic polynomial are simple, then the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: "If all the roots are simple" does that mean roots of degree 1? Surely this polynomial can have a maximum of one root as it is irreducible?

Comment: @user9078057 I meant complex roots. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Still do not understand how that ties in with my thinking

Comment: @user9078057 Yes, “all the roots are simple” means that they all have degree $1$. On the other hand, suppose that $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and that the characteristic polynomial is $x^2+1$. This polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but it has two (simple) complex roots.

Comment: Yes, I get that but how can it be diagonalizable if there is only one simple root $\lambda$ because $1=dim_{K}(V_{\lambda})$

Comment: @user9078057 What I mean os that it is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$. Note how the the sentence is constructed: “Prove that $M \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is diagonalizable.”, not “Prove that $M \in M_{n}(K)$ is diagonalizable.”

Comment: How does diagonalizability differ from a $\mathbb C$ to $K$? Surely $dim_{K}(V)=1$ still holds

Comment: @user9078057 If $K=\mathbb Q$ and $M=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then the characteristic polynomial is $x^2+1$, which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Since it has no rational roots, $M$ is not diagonalizable in $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$. However, it is diagonalizable in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.